# Using a date function on a column that has different types

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Is it possible to use a function like DATEADD() or DATEPART() on a varchar column that may or may not hold something that looks like a datetime?

Currently I'm trying this by using a WHERE clause to select only rows that have datetime values in this column and getting the usual arithmetic overflow error.

I could perform some sort of operation to extract just the datetime values and put them in a temp table but I'm curious about this.

Example

```
SELECT DATEPART(wk, DateCreated) FROM tblOrders WHERE colType = 'datetime'
```

<strike>Don't</strike> worry about the table design, it's <strike>not</strike> as bad as that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Don't worry about the table design, it's not as bad as that.

Seems unlikely, but...

Use [`IsDate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)

Comment: A little punch and a a proper answer in just three lines... :-)

Comment: I never even thought of using IsDate(). But still, I couldn't use DATEPART() on the column with this in my WHERE clause. Ended up going the temp table route anyway because, as it turns out, the table design sucks harder than I initially realised. Also edited my post after some frustration in creating a report today.